# ASP.Net 4.0 Type not found when using MS Report control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, reportviewer

Hi 
  I'm trying to build an ASP.Net c# application using the report control, it works fine on my PC running from VS2010 but when I publish it to my web site which is a shared hosting system I get:

```
    'Type' is undefined  Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.1&Name=ViewerScript, line 1 character 1

  'Microsoft' is undefined  Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.1&Name=ViewerScript, line 3 character 1
```

If I copy the web site I get an additional error which seems to be caused / suppressed by web.config Debug when true I get:

```
ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.  PcMainReport.aspx, line 41 character 34
```

the application is loaded to a sub domain not sure if that is relevant, the asp menu control and membership both work fine!

Googling I found this:
"After resetting the root application (by inheriting from the machine configuration) the proper entries were propagated throughout the site and the report works fine now"
at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/3a6127c4-3ecd-4a89-aa78-8a8a8e4cd7a6

I have no Idea how to do this or if this is my issue!?

my Web.config section is:

```
 <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Comment: OK I don't know what they did yet, but the ISP web hosting company have fixed it!

Comment: IIS7 Manager site, handlers > reset to default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably installed the Report Viewer redistributable package for you.  Good on them!  http://www.programgood.net/2011/01/21/ReportviewerRedistributable.aspx